# Error - Duplicates in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to remove duplicates in excel and have been successful in doing that. I have certain gaps in my spreadsheet after running the code is where I need help. Below is the entire explanation:

1) I copy records from two different files in to a separate file and have 17 columns (A to R).
2) I look for duplicates and remove.
3) 3 Blank rows appear between the last record and second last record after removal of duplicates.(Picture attached)
[image]

```
With y.Sheets("RL Holdings").Activate
    Set rng = Range("A2", Range("R2").End(xlDown))
    rng.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1), Header:=xlYes
End With
```

Comment: Do you want to now remove the blank rows?  Or something else?

Comment: @RalphJ When I use Q instead of R in the range, the R column has more entries then others,which is understood but then there are no empty rows in between. Empty rows just appear when I use R as range, which I want to be the range. So do you think that it's just the empty rows that need to be deleted? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, but your comment doesn't entirely clarify your problem. Could you try and further elaborate?

Comment: @Tom When I Set rng = Range("A2", Range("R2").End(xlDown)), there are blank records betwwen last and second last but when I use Set rng = Range("A2", Range("Q2").End(xlDown)), there are no blank rows, but just more values in R column which is expected as I didn't take R in my second code . Why doesnt the same logic work when I choose Range("R2").End(xlDown) as my range. Hope you get this or I can edit it properly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I only see up to column J in your example. I am guessing cell R18 is empty, so that .End will not select the last row, but Q18 has something in it.